# How to interpolate random non monotonic increasing data

Tags: matlab, interpolation, spline

So I am working on my Thesis and I need to calculate geometric characteristics of an airfoil.

To do this, I need to interpolate the horizontal and vertical coordinates of an airfoil. This is used for a tool which will calculate the geometric characteristics automatically which come from random airfoil geometry files.

Sometime the Y values of the airfoil are non monotonic. Hence, the interp1 command gives an error since some values in the Y vector are repeated.

Therefore, my question is: How do I recognize and subsequently interpolate non monotonic increasing data automatically in Matlab.

Here is a sample data set:

```
 0.999974    0.002176
 0.994846    0.002555
 0.984945    0.003283
 0.973279    0.004131
 0.960914    0.005022
 0.948350    0.005919
 0.935739    0.006810
 0.923111    0.007691
 0.910478    0.008564
 0.897850    0.009428
 0.885229    0.010282
 0.872617    0.011125
 0.860009    0.011960
 0.847406    0.012783
 0.834807    0.013598
 0.822210    0.014402
 0.809614    0.015199
 0.797021    0.015985
 0.784426    0.016764
 0.771830    0.017536
 0.759236    0.018297
 0.746639    0.019053
 0.734038    0.019797
 0.721440    0.020531
 0.708839    0.021256
 0.696240    0.021971
 0.683641    0.022674
 0.671048    0.023367
 0.658455    0.024048
 0.645865    0.024721
 0.633280    0.025378
 0.620699    0.026029
 0.608123    0.026670
 0.595552    0.027299
 0.582988    0.027919
 0.570436    0.028523
 0.557889    0.029115
 0.545349    0.029697
 0.532818    0.030265
 0.520296    0.030820
 0.507781    0.031365
 0.495276    0.031894
 0.482780    0.032414
 0.470292    0.032920
 0.457812    0.033415
 0.445340    0.033898
 0.432874    0.034369
 0.420416    0.034829
 0.407964    0.035275
 0.395519    0.035708
 0.383083    0.036126
 0.370651    0.036530
 0.358228    0.036916
 0.345814    0.037284
 0.333403    0.037629
 0.320995    0.037950
 0.308592    0.038244
 0.296191    0.038506
 0.283793    0.038733
 0.271398    0.038920
 0.259004    0.039061
 0.246612    0.039153
 0.234221    0.039188
 0.221833    0.039162
 0.209446    0.039064
 0.197067    0.038889
 0.184693    0.038628
 0.172330    0.038271
 0.159986    0.037809
 0.147685    0.037231
 0.135454    0.036526
 0.123360    0.035684
 0.111394    0.034690
 0.099596    0.033528
 0.088011    0.032181
 0.076685    0.030635
 0.065663    0.028864
 0.055015    0.026849
 0.044865    0.024579
 0.035426    0.022076
 0.027030    0.019427
 0.019970    0.016771
 0.014377    0.014268
 0.010159    0.012029
 0.007009    0.010051
 0.004650    0.008292
 0.002879    0.006696
 0.001578    0.005207
 0.000698    0.003785
 0.000198    0.002434
 0.000000    0.001190
 0.000000    0.000000
 0.000258   -0.001992
 0.000832   -0.003348
 0.001858   -0.004711
 0.003426   -0.005982
 0.005568   -0.007173
 0.008409   -0.008303
 0.012185   -0.009379
 0.017243   -0.010404
 0.023929   -0.011326
 0.032338   -0.012056
 0.042155   -0.012532
 0.052898   -0.012742
 0.064198   -0.012720
 0.075846   -0.012533
 0.087736   -0.012223
 0.099803   -0.011837
 0.111997   -0.011398
 0.124285   -0.010925
 0.136634   -0.010429
 0.149040   -0.009918
 0.161493   -0.009400
 0.173985   -0.008878
 0.186517   -0.008359
 0.199087   -0.007845
 0.211686   -0.007340
 0.224315   -0.006846
 0.236968   -0.006364
 0.249641   -0.005898
 0.262329   -0.005451
 0.275030   -0.005022
 0.287738   -0.004615
 0.300450   -0.004231
 0.313158   -0.003870
 0.325864   -0.003534
 0.338565   -0.003224
 0.351261   -0.002939
 0.363955   -0.002680
 0.376646   -0.002447
 0.389333   -0.002239
 0.402018   -0.002057
 0.414702   -0.001899
 0.427381   -0.001766
 0.440057   -0.001656
 0.452730   -0.001566
 0.465409   -0.001496
 0.478092   -0.001443
 0.490780   -0.001407
 0.503470   -0.001381
 0.516157   -0.001369
 0.528844   -0.001364
 0.541527   -0.001368
 0.554213   -0.001376
 0.566894   -0.001386
 0.579575   -0.001398
 0.592254   -0.001410
 0.604934   -0.001424
 0.617614   -0.001434
 0.630291   -0.001437
 0.642967   -0.001443
 0.655644   -0.001442
 0.668323   -0.001439
 0.681003   -0.001437
 0.693683   -0.001440
 0.706365   -0.001442
 0.719048   -0.001444
 0.731731   -0.001446
 0.744416   -0.001443
 0.757102   -0.001445
 0.769790   -0.001444
 0.782480   -0.001445
 0.795173   -0.001446
 0.807870   -0.001446
 0.820569   -0.001446
 0.833273   -0.001446
 0.845984   -0.001448
 0.858698   -0.001448
 0.871422   -0.001451
 0.884148   -0.001448
 0.896868   -0.001446
 0.909585   -0.001443
 0.922302   -0.001445
 0.935019   -0.001446
 0.947730   -0.001446
 0.960405   -0.001439
 0.972917   -0.001437
 0.984788   -0.001441
 0.994843   -0.001441
 1.000019   -0.001441
```

First column is X and the second column is Y. Notice how the last values of Y are repeated.

Maybe someone can provide me with a piece of code to do this? Or any suggestions are welcome as well.

Remember I need to automate this process.

Thanks for your time and effort I really appreciate it!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to interpolate? Are the Y values supposed to be interpolated? What code did you try?

Comment: Define a 2D interpolation grid and use [`interp2`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)

Comment: @Hoki  yes I will try to implement this and see whether it works or not

Comment: @rlbond I am trying to interpolate the Y values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is quick and dirty method if you do not know the exact function defining the foil profile. Split your data into 2 sets, top and bottom planes, so the 'x' data are `monotonic increasing`.

First I imported your data table in the variable `A`, then:

```
%// just reorganise your input in individual vectors. (this is optional but
%// if you do not do it you'll have to adjust the code below)
x = A(:,1) ;    
y = A(:,2) ;

ipos = y >  0 ;                             %// indices of the top plane
ineg = y <= 0 ;                             %// indices of the bottom plane

xi = linspace(0,1,500) ;                    %// new Xi for interpolation

ypos = interp1( x(ipos) , y(ipos) , xi ) ;  %// re-interp the top plane
yneg = interp1( x(ineg) , y(ineg) , xi ) ;  %// re-interp the bottom plane

y_new = [fliplr(yneg) ypos] ;               %// stiches the two half data set together
x_new = [fliplr(xi) xi] ;

%% // display
figure
plot(x,y,'o')
hold on
plot(x_new,y_new,'.r')
axis equal
```

[image: foil]

As said on top, it is quick and dirty. As you can see from the detail figure, you can greatly improve the `x` resolution this way in the area where the profile is close to the horizontal direction, but you loose a bit of resolution at the noose of the foil where the profile is close to the vertical direction.

---

If it's acceptable then you're all set. If you really need the resolution at the nose, you could look at interpolating on `x` as above but do a very fine `x` grid near the noose (instead of the regular `x` grid I provided as example).
if your replace the `xi` definition above by:

```
xi = [linspace(0,0.01,50) linspace(0.01,1,500)] ;
```

You get the following near the nose:

[image: foildetail]

adjust that to your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I've actually tried this method before. It quick and cheap and gives me reasonable answers actually. But thanks my problem is solved now

Answer (score 2):

To interpolate any function, there must be a function defined. When you define `y=f(x)`, you cannot have the same `x` for two different values of `y` because then we are not talking about a function. In your example data, neither `x` nor `y` are monotonic, so anyway you slice it, you'll have two (or more) "y"s for the same "x". If you wish to interpolate, you need to divide this into two separate problems, top/bottom and define proper functions for `interp1/2/n` to work with, for example, slice it horizontally where `x==0`. In any case, you would have to provide additional info than just `x` or `y` alone, e.g.: `x=0.5` and `y` is on top.

[image: This is your air foil]

On the other hand, if all you want to do is to insert a few values between each `x` and `y` in your array, you can do this using finite differences:

```
%// transform your original xy into 3d array where x is in first slice and y in second
xy = permute(xy(85:95,:), [3,1,2]); %// 85:95 is near x=0 in your data

%// lets say you want to insert three additional points along each line between every two points on given airfoil
h = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75].'; %// steps along each line - column vector

%// every interpolated h along the way between f(x(n)) and f(x(n+1))  can
%// be defined as: f(x(n) + h) = f(x(n)) + h*( f(x(n+1)) - f(x(n)) )
%// this is first order finite differences approximation in 1D. 2D is very
%// similar only with gradient (this should be common knowledge, look it up)

%// from here it's just fancy matrix play

%// 2D gradient of xy curve
gradxy = diff(xy, 1, 2); %// diff xy, first order, along the 2nd dimension, where x and y now run
h_times_gradxy = bsxfun(@times, h, gradxy); %// gradient times step size
xy_in_3d_array = bsxfun(@plus, xy(:,1:end-1,:), h_times_gradxy); %// addition of "f(x)" and there we have it, the new x and y for every step h
[x,y] = deal(xy_in_3d_array(:,:,1), xy_in_3d_array(:,:,2)); %// extract x and y from 3d matrix
xy_interp = [x(:), y(:)]; %// use Matlab's linear indexing to flatten x and y into columns

%// plot to check results
figure; ax = newplot; hold on;
plot(ax, xy(:,:,1), xy(:,:,2),'o-');
plot(ax, xy_interp(:,1), xy_interp(:,2),'+')
legend('Original','Interpolated',0);
axis tight;
grid;

%// The End
```

And these are the results, near `x=0` for clarity of presentation:

[image]

Hope that helps. 
Cheers.

Comment: Hey @Alexander F, Yeah did split my data into an upper and lower region and am trying to interpolate them separately. See the piece of code below:  `%% Find leading edge (Xcoor=0)
iLE = find(Xcoor==0,1,'first');
UpperX = Xnorm(iLE:-1:1);
UpperY = Ynorm(iLE:-1:1);
            
LowerX = Xnorm(iLE:end);
LowerY = Ynorm(iLE:end);`

Comment: As for you suggestion, I need to automate this procedure so I cannot say ''85:95 is near x=0 in your data'' Hence, another clever way should be implemented to make your code usefull for me

Comment: @BalrajBoyal, I thought it was clear, "near x=0" was there for **clarity of presentation**, meaning, so it can be shown that it works, and how it works. You can easily put your entire data set as input to the above code: `xy = permute(xy, [3,1,2]);`.